# Divide results into tabs in View Inquiry (Generic Inquiry)

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

In the screen Generic Inquiry (SM208000), I choose SO-Invoice and click VIEW INQUIRY, it leads to a screen that have some tabs are classified query results by Invoices Type.

My question is that can I create my generic inquiry with those tabs in my Inquiry screen?

[image]

I read some documents and didn't find any information about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, these tabs are saved filters for the Generic Inquiry.
You can configure them using the Funnel button on top of the screen. You'll need to define filtering criteria there and provide a name for the filter. After you save it, it will appear as a separate tab.
You can also configure and review existing filters using Filters form (CS209010).

Comment: Not recommended because it's not officially supported but if for some reason you need to inspect those values, they can be fetched from the session object, ex for GI000000: PXContext.Session.PageInfo["GI.00.00.00PX.Data.PXGenericInqGrph$PX.Data.GenericFilter"] as object[]

Comment: Thank you so much! I found it!